# How to hide a text on hoverring over 'menu' element

Tags: jquery

I want to hide a text in my website on hovering over the 'menu' element and display it back when the hovering ends. How can I implement it?

Comment: where is your html? post it here,  then only we can help you

Comment: Welcome to SO - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var el = $('#idOfElementTohideOnHover');

    $('#idOfMenuItem').hover(function(){
      el.hide();
    },function(){
      el.show();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="hoverclass">text</div>
```

css

```
.hoverclass:hover{
  color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Isn't visibility:hidden property of css more convenient way to achieve this?

Comment: @Foreever its up to you, but what i think is, if you ``hide()`` the text, the space will be gone. with transparency, it just disappears and its space will be there, so there is be no change in layout.

Comment: This is what visibility:hidden do,hiding without any change in layout. I think you confused this with display:none.

Answer (score 0):

```
.menuItem:hover{
  -moz-opacity: 0;
  -khtml-opacity: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha"(Opacity=0);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0);
}
```